# Referencing a subfolder on server with local site being root

Tags: php

This maybe a simple task, but I build sites in php locally and then upload them to a subfolder for clients approval. All this is fine, but when i'm building the site, I use references to the root, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/css/custom.css">
```

And when this is published to the site it is obviously a level to low. What would be the bet way (mainly for ease of life for me) to just upload files with-out having to remember to change the paths.

I did use

`<? $root = "subfolder/"; ?> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $root;?>/stylesheets/css/custom.css">`

But it seems a bit clunky... Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution, you might not thought of:

Simply change the `/stylesheets/css/custom.css` to `stylesheets/css/custom.css` ( removing the first slash ) and then if you upload it to a subfolder it won't mess up..

The reason that this happens is that when you type `/` in the first of a path it goes to the root automatically. So if your site is on the root then you might not have a problem but if it is on a subfolder than it will mess up...

Comment: I had thought of this, but, some of the files (namely the header) include links to the rest of the site in the navigation, and they could be in folders, as such they need the / Guess I should have added that...

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the file that you're in using `__FILE__`... or the directory using `__DIR__`.  These may help you set up a constant or similar pointing to your "root" from where you can then use references relative to this throughout your code.

Refer [PHP Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)